# C# Substituir partes de String em arquivo txt

Tags: c#

Olá.

Estou estudando C# e estou com dificuldade em uma função.

Tenho um array, como abaixo, onde cada nó contém um um id, um pattern(regex) e um valor para substituição da parte da string que der match por esse valor.

Carrego o conteúdo do arquivo txt em contenFile e se , por exemplo, der match com alguma parte do contenFile , substitui-se o match com "ABC" e assim com as demais posições do array. Se não der match, insere o valor no fim.

O arquivo contem campos para dar match e não match

< tag 101" >
      < tag2 >BBBBBBBBBBB< /tag2 >
      < tag4 >CCCCCCCC< /tag4 >
< tag 101" >

Se alguém puder ajudar ou indicar algum conteúdo para estudo, agradeço.

No momento o código se encontra assim:

```
public void Edit()
{
string[,] items = {{"001", "<tag ([0-9]{3})\">", "ABC"},
                    {"002", "<tag2>.+</tag2>", "DEF"},
                    {"", "<tag3>.+</tag3>", "GHI"}};
try
{
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\test.xml"))
{
string contentFile = sr.ReadToEnd();

foreach (string entry in items)
{
if (!Regex.IsMatch(contentFile, entry[1].ToString()))
{
contentFile = contentFile.Insert(contentFile.Length, entry[2].ToString());
}
else
{
contentFile = Regex.Replace(contentFile, entry[1].ToString(), entry[2].ToString());
}
}
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
}
```

Comment: E o que ele está capturando? O que quer capturar?

Comment: A idéia é criar um novo arquivo com os dados editados(ainda não fiz pq essa parte não funciona). Porém, não consigo setar os novos valores no contentFile para depois escrever no arquivo. Permanecem os dados carregados do arquivo original.

Comment: Por que você não usa um interpretador de XML e altera os nomes das tags em seguida?

Comment: O Exercício deve ser feito com um arquivo de texto hehehe. Eu coloquei a estrutura de xml por estética msm, mas devo manipular ele como um txt.